# kth largest element in all possible products of two arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Given two arrays `A` and `B` each of size `N` how to find the `K`th largest element among the set `X = {i x j | i ∈ A and j ∈ B}`?

I came up with `O(N^2 log(n))` solution by forming the set `X`, sorting it and then finding element at `K`th position from last. Is there a better solution which has lower complexity?

Answer (score 3):

Given a candidate number, you can check in time O(N) using two pointers in the sorted representations of A and B what rank it has in the set {i x j | i ∈ A and j ∈ B}. Hence one possible solution is to use binary search on the value of i x j, with a runtime of O(N * (log N + log U)) where U is the size of the universe from which A and B are drawn.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how to find rank of given number in O(N)?

Comment: Could you also please elaborate how to detect the rank of a given `i x j` given that it must include knowledge of how many ways any one `i x j` value and any smaller `i x j` value may be created from different `(i, j)` combinations?

Comment: @Lokesh Given some value v and i, you basically want to count how many numbers are <  v - i in B. That can be determined via binary search in B, or by just maintaining a pointer while iterating over increasing i.

Comment: @גלעדברקן The trick is that for a fixed i you can compute the number of valid j's in (amortized) O(1) time

Comment: Will we be able to check its rank in the set in O(N) time if there are negative numbers in the A and B as well?

Comment: I feel it can be done but we will need to consider the positive and the negative elements separately. It will be something like 2 pairs of two pointers :) 


1) One pointer starts on the smallest negative number in A. The other pointer is on the largest positive number in B.


2) One pointer starts on the smallest positive number in A and the other pointer starts on the smallest negative number in B.

Answer (score 1):

There is a low-hanging fruit here - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect
(pay attention to the last section - it's possible to have worst case performance O(n) as well)

You just create array with all products and then select k-th element using the algorithm mentioned above. In total it will be O(n^2).

But I suspect there should be something better here...

Comment: Same approach can be modified by appropriately selecting pivot using medianofmedians approach so that this works in worst case O(n) time actually.